# Multipart Identifier "arafa.almahmud08@gmail.com" couldnot be bound

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have built a custom validator,

I have a sql query like this:

```
protected void custom_serverValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        connect();
        string strSQL = "select EmailAddress from Accounts_Users where EmailAddress=" + REmailTextBox.Text;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, objConnection);
        if (e.Value.ToString() == cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString())
        {
            e.IsValid = false;
        }
        else
            e.IsValid = true;
        disConnect();
    }
```

when I execute my code in the browser and an email address and submit it , I get the error mentioned in the title. how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes around your email address.  However - this is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.  Please switch to using a parameter.

```
string strSQL = "select EmailAddress from Accounts_Users where EmailAddress = @EmailAddress"

...

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", REmailTextBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use the single quotes. Use:

```
string commandText = "select EmailAddress from Accounts_Users where EmailAddress=@EmailAttress";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", REmailTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: changed answer to add parameters. Although I usually prefer to leave those out as a learning experience for those who ask about this kind of stuff. This should protect you from basic SQL injection as well as fix the original problem.